# Create Domain class in Grails

Tags: grails

I am new to Grails and have a question: 
I set the environment to production and want to make "new"  domain variable. I am wondering where it will be stored in db or memory? If in db how could I store it in memory or vice versa (in runtime)?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "store in memory"? You want to make some tests that don't affect the database?

Comment: Have you looked at this amazing website http://www.grails.org

Comment: yes, that should be temporary.

Comment: Do you want to have one transient instance or the whole class should be transient?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411537/possible-to-create-a-domain-class-that-is-not-mapped-to-a-database-table or so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should I place a transient domain class in a grails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051720/where-should-i-place-a-transient-domain-class-in-a-grails-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Non-persistent-domain-class-td2336815.html

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Best-practice-for-quot-transient-domain-objects-quot-td1389709.html

[Where should I place a transient domain class in a grails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051720/where-should-i-place-a-transient-domain-class-in-a-grails-app)

Answer (score 0):

The default grails application stores it in "memory" (when run in dev mode) and it depends on the DataSource.groovy setting
url = "jdbc:h2:**file**:~/data/.h2Dev"

If it's file it will be stored in file. If it's mem it will be stored in memory